# c# reference to string in FIM

Tags: c#

I'm writing a rule extension for Microsoft Identity Manager (FIM / MIM) and have a problem.
What I want:
I have an attribute "Manager" which is references to user manager. I need to look for this attribute and populate another attribute in MS AD with account name of manager.
I have a such code which must be working, but I get error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to access attribute manager. Reference values not accessible on MV objects.
>       at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.AttributeImpl.get_Value()
>       at Mms_ManagementAgent_HRExt.MAExtensionObject.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport(String FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry) in C:......HRExt.cs:line 213

at this point

```
mvMGRemployeeID = mventry["ManagerID"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
```

Code is below:

```
string mvMGRemployeeID;    //temp string that holds the supervisor code
MVEntry[] mgrSearch;    //Collection of MV Etriers used to perform the search forMV object based on the manager employeeID

if (mventry["ManagerID"].IsPresent)
{
    mvMGRemployeeID = mventry["MAnagerID"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
    mgrSearch= Utils.FindMVEntries("employeeID", mvMGRemployeeID, 1); //Is there an object with employeeID = ManagerID

    if (mgrDNSearch.Length == 1)//if we get only one return (which we should)
    {
        if (mgrDNSearch[0]["accountName"].IsPresent) //get the DN of the returned object
        {
            csentry["manager"].Value = mgrDNSearch[0]["accountName"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added MAnagerID in dependencies.
and simply you can do:

```
mvMGRemployeeID = "" + csentry["MAnagerID"].ReferenceValue;
```

Thank you